# Larvel model to not auto generated Id if id is provided

Tags: php, laravel

Newbie question here,
I'm having an employee/profile model, where I have a boot function to create a user on the creation of the employee model.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::created(function($model)
    {
       $User = new \App\Models\User;
         $User->id = $model->id;
          $User->name = $model->first_name.' '.$model->last_name;
          $User->email = $model->work_email;
          $User->save();

    });
```

while checking the DB i notice it's not picking the employee ID (UUID) and saving the same id as user ID

```
$User->id = $model->id;
```

what I'm doing wrong here ?

i have found that i can update it after saving
by adding

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::created(function($model)
    {
       $User = new \App\Models\User;
         $User->id = $model->id;
          $User->name = $model->first_name.' '.$model->last_name;
          $User->email = $model->work_email;
          $User->save();
          $User->id = $model->id;
          $User->save();


    });
}
```

is there is way to do it without saving two times?

Answer (score 2):

You are fundamentally misunderstanding how database relations should be created. You do not indicate that two entries are related by giving them the same ID.

You do it by creating a foreign key between the two tables in your migration:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('employee_id')->constrained('employees');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
    });
}
```

And then creating a relationship in your ORM.

```php
class User extends Authenticatable {
    public function employee() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class);
    }
}
class Employee extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }
}
```

And then your event handler looks like this:

```php
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::created(function ($model) {
       $u = User::make([
           'name' => $model->first_name . ' ' . $model->last_name,
           'email' => $model->work_email,
       ]);
       $u->employee = $model;
       $u->save();
    });
}
```

Now you have related user to employee, such that you can do things like this:

```php
$user = User::find(123);
echo $user->employee->first_name;
```

Comment: In that case, don't you think it's still redundant having `name` and `email` data duplicated in both entities? I think it's more appropriate to have a single source of truth.

Comment: It absolutely is, but I didn't want to get into all that. It's unlikely the OP is going to fix their architecture anyway, they will probably just do what's easiest to copy and paste. I just wanted to point out the proper way to do it.

Comment: Hi @miken32 , thank you for your response, I completely understand the concept, however as you stated I  just wanted an easy way, and there was no thought off architecture to begin with, to fix. , just do something small and without much of pre-desgin.

Comment: just to explain as my previous comment for name and email, not all users (model) will be in the employee model.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`forceCreate(...)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b12f44c37bc057e98757743cd67ba47e934dac2a/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L904) instead.

> Save a new model and return the instance. Allow mass-assignment.

```php
\App\Models\User::forceCreate([
    "id" => $model->id,
    "name" => $model->first_name . ' ' . $model->last_name,
    "email" => $model->work_email,
]);
```

##### Addendum

Alternatively, you may use [`forceFill(...)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b12f44c37bc057e98757743cd67ba47e934dac2a/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L449)

> Fill the model with an array of attributes. Force mass assignment.

```php
(new \App\Models\User)->forceFill([
    "id" => $model->id,
    "name" => $model->first_name . ' ' . $model->last_name,
    "email" => $model->work_email,
])->save();
```

Comment: I've tried it, and I get the same result it ignores the provided ID and have a new ID.

Comment: @SamerAjlawi Try using `forceFill(...)` as specified in my answer. If that doesn't work, edit your question and show us your `\App\Models\User.php` model file.

Comment: Setting a property on the model is not "mass assignment." The `$fillable` property has no effect.

Comment: @miken32 You're right, I stand corrected. Removed the mass assignment content from the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @steven7mwesigwa. i will just stick with the original thought or go with the proper one to one relation

Answer (score -1):

If you create a new user, you shouldn't add `id`. If you want to update an existing user, you should use for example [find](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) instead of creating a new model object

Comment: The resource link in your answer corresponds to *"[Retrieving Single Models / Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)"* yet your instructions are referring to *"updating an existing user"* which doesn't make sense.